# Plot histogram showing theoretical distribution of binomial random variable

Tags: r, histogram, distribution

Plot a histogram showing the theoretical distribution of a binomial random variable X with n = 10 and p = 0.5, labeling your plot. The following command might be helpful after assigning d with `dbinom`:

```
gf_line(d ~ 0:10)
```

I have no idea where to start with this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Thank to jay.sf (see comment)

```
x=0:10
y <- dbinom(x,10,0.5)

plot(x,y, type='h')
```

[image]

Comment: Why the sampling of `x`? I believe, just `x=0:10` would be fine, because it's the theoretical distribution.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your valuable comment. It is just a matter of how I create my random integer usually. In this case `x=0:10`is efficient enough.

Comment: Yeah now it's great +1 (wasn't my downvote btw).